# IE6 transparency problem for dynamic images

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, png

I am trying to use the various techniques with dynamic png images i.e. images added after the page has been loaded using javascript DOM.

All of the techniques I tried seem to fail. Is there a reliable technqiue for the same?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [this fix from TwinHelix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) on pretty complex websites with great success :)

One caveat through (this applies to all "fixes" i believe) is that you can not make a background image of an element be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

http://allinthehead.com/retro/338/supersleight-jquery-plugin

Better yet, don't waste your time developing for IE6.  I know this makes me flamebait, but the more new sites that work poorly on IE6, the more pressure we put on people to move on to at least IE7.  The amount of hacking you will have to do around IE6 to make a *great* many things is something you really need to sit down and strongly consider.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good jQuery plugin called [pngFix](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/).